# Reading XML with invalid XML Processing Instruction using System.Xml.XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xml, system.xml

I am trying to read XML from a server I'm connecting to. Unfortunately, I don't have a way of correcting this on their end. I am getting an exception:

```
Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 3.
```

I believe this is because they begin the data with `<? LLSD/XML ?>` and given that the third character is a   it throws this exception. My question is, how can I get around this? The rest of the data is valid XML. I have been able to parse this successfully in C++ using expat, tinyxml, etc, but System.Xml.XmlReader fails it. Currently, I am doing this:

```
        public static OSD DeserializeLLSDXml(Stream xmlStream)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                ValidationType = ValidationType.None,
                CheckCharacters = false,
                IgnoreComments = true,
                IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true,
                DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit
            };
            using (XmlReader xrd = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream))
            {
                return DeserializeLLSDXml(xrd);
            }
        }
    
        public static OSD DeserializeLLSDXml(XmlReader xmlData)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlData.Read();
                SkipWhitespace(xmlData);

                xmlData.Read();
                OSD ret = ParseLLSDXmlElement(xmlData);

                return ret;
            }
            catch (XmlException ex)
            {
                string exs = ex.ToString();
                return new OSD();
            }
        }
```

Example message I receive:

```
<? LLSD/XML ?>\n
<llsd>
  <map>
    <key>MINUTES</key>
    <integer>5</integer>
    <key>NAME</key>
    <string>Hippotropolis</string>
  </map>
</llsd>\n
```

Comment: That isn't a declaration but a processing instruction (these are often confused; a declaration specifically starts with `<?xml` and nothing else). It is, as you've discovered, an invalid PI; more lax parsers may accept it if they just skip anything inside `<?` that's not a declaration. `XmlReader` cannot be made to skip it ("ignore" just means "do not surface this in reads", not "ignore any errors"), instead you will have to advance the stream beyond the invalid PI before passing it to the reader. If you know it's always there, you can use a `StreamReader` and `.ReadLine()` first.

Comment: Repairing bad XML will never be 100% reliable, but in this instance, replacing `<? ` by `<?` is unlikely to do much harm, unless you are very unlucky.

Comment: @MichaelKay: replacing things in a stream is a bit tricky, though. It's also not enough, because a PI can't legally include `/` either. You'd have to replace all of `<? LLSD/XML ?>` with something innocuous, and if you're going to do that you may as well go all the way and skip it (and/or everything inside `<?` and `?>`, as other parsers seem to do).

Comment: Yes, replacing  `<?`  by `<?pi ` would be safer. Assuming you don't care about the PI content.

Comment: After taking @JeroenMostert's advice into consideration, I just read the beginning of the Stream for a match to `<? LLSD/` if there is no match, I seek back to the beginning of the stream and pass to the XmlReader. If there is a match, I continue reading until reaching the newline, and then pass the Stream at that position to XmlReader. Seems to work well and covers both cases where the PI exists and where it does not.